# contenteditable pre scrollbars not showing correct cursor

Tags: html, css

I have a contenteditable, and in it I can have pre tags, which I have stylized to show a thinner scrollbar. But now the scrollbar cursor (seen when hovering over the scrollbar) remains as a text style instead of pointer. I have tried adding the obvious `cursor:pointer` to the -webkit settings but nothing seems to work.
How do I make the pre scrollbar use a pointer cursor instead of text?

```css
    pre {
      padding: 10px;
      width: calc(100% - 70px);
      overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    
    pre::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
    }
    
    pre::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: #9c9c9c;
      -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    }
```

```html
 <div contenteditable>
    
    <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Quis varius quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar. Turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa. Sed risus pretium quam vulputate</pre>
    
    </div>
```

Use https://jsfiddle.net/Lhmsf38k/ to have a fiddle.

Comment: I have just met a same issue. Do you have solution for it ?

Comment: Still not solved